# How To Convert YouTube Video Durations From ISO8601

Tags: ios, youtube, iso8601

I'm dynamically pulling videos from a specific YouTube channel in my app, and the entire process is working well, except for pulling the video durations. I can get as far as loading the duration from YouTube as an ISO8601 string (i.e. PT1M15S), but I have no idea how to convert this to an NSString to place into a Label. How would I go about this conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link: https://github.com/boredzo/iso-8601-date-formatter . It's a ISO8601 string converters. I  used it a project and it works like a charm :)